# Перекрыть нижний блок тенью от верхнего

Tags: css, sass

Делаю блок со вкладками, который имеет определенный border-radius. Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы активная вкладка перекрывала закругленный край нижнего блока, так как сейчас это не выглядит не очень красиво. Пробовал использовать z-index: 1 и box-shadow снизу активной вкладки, но тень не отображается, видимо из-за того, что тень находится за границами родительского блока. Если есть решение без перекрытия блоков, тоже замечательно.

[image: пример элемента]

```css
.categoriesTabs
    max-width: 100%
    margin-top: 15px

    .tabs
        white-space: pre
        overflow-x: auto

        .categoriesTab
            background-color: $backgroundColor
            color: $textColor
            border-top-left-radius: 1rem
            border-top-right-radius: 1rem
            border: none
            padding: 8px 16px
            text-align: left
            margin-left: 0px
            margin-right: 0px
            font-size: 21px
            outline: none

            &.active
                background-color: $categoryTabActiveColor

        .categoriesTab:focus
            outline: 0 !important

    .categoryContent
        background-color: $categoryTabActiveColor
        padding: 1rem
        border-radius: 1rem
```

```html
<div hidden={hidden} className='categoriesTabs'>
            <div className='tabs'>
                {categories.map((category, counter) => (
                    <button
                        className={"categoriesTab" + (activeCategory === category ? " active" : "")}
                        key={counter}
                        onClick={() => {
                            onChangeCategory(category);
                        }}>
                        {category}
                    </button>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div className='categoryContent'>{children}</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: так просто в выпадающем меню левый верхний бордер не ставьте

Comment: Ну это не совсем то, там весь блок имеет бордер, если убирать левый верхний, то и правый верхний тоже. Тогда блок будет выглядеть странно, снизу есть скругления, а сверху нет

Comment: так там как раз не будёт видно его, вообше можно сделать псевдоелемент на высоту <= верхнего падинга, спозиционировать в нижнем углу и закрасить

Comment: если активна первая вкладка, то да, не видно. Но если переключиться на соседнюю, то видно. А если делать псевдоэлемент, то придется управлять его видимостью в зависимости от того, какая вкладка активна. Если я правильно уловил суть

Comment: не ну никто вам не запрещаем табы делать радиокнопками и творить беспредел как тут https://codepen.io/istavros/pen/hiuvF, не вижу особой проблемы не сделать простенькую реализацию на js)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри данный вопрос, возможно будет полезным, там похожая проблема

[Добавить стиль последнему элементу строки грид](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253049/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b4/1253077#1253077)